# How to disable atom feed and only use RSS feed

Tags: rss

Is there a way to disable atom feed and have only rss feed? When I click on the RSS button on my Firefox, I am show 'subscribe to domaintitle using RSS feeds' and 'subscribe to domaintitle using atom feeds'

I do not use a plugin but rather a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feed links that are included in the HTML code depend on your theme. For example, *Twenty Ten* only includes one feed type (with two feeds: posts and comments). Check your `header.php` to see which feeds are referenced there.

If it is a modern theme (like Twenty Ten), you might see no feed links there. This is because WordPress calls [`feed_links()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1591) in `wp_head`, which will (if the theme supports `automatic-feed-links`) output links for posts and entries in the default feed format, [which is `rss2`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/feed.php#L52) if you don't change it via the `default_feed` filter.

Additionally, on some pages like category archives, [`feed_links_extra()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1617) will also output links for a feed for only that category, again in the default feed format.

If you really want to disable a feed (so requests for `example.com/atom` will no longer work), you can do something like two7s_clash suggested, or play with the rewrite rules so `atom` is no longer part of the allowed feeds.

Answer (score 3):

```
function disable_our_feeds() {
    wp_die( __('<strong>Error:</strong> No RSS Feed Available, Please visit our <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>.') );
}

add_action('do_feed_atom', 'disable_our_feeds', 1);
```